# How can I access localhost upload.php using apache2 proxy setting from my locally running AngularJS application

Tags: php, angularjs, apache2

I am running an AngularJS application in my local host port number 9090 which is trying to save an image. I found a quick w3 schools [PHP5 Upload link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) to upload an image. So, Using this method I can quickly verify whether my upload image concept is working or not. When I access this without proxy, this link works fine.

When, I tried to access this link using proxy pass reverse from my AngularJS application, I am not able to access it.

I don't know anything on PHP and I just want to verify the image upload works fine or not.

My Apache2 configuration is here and it is listening on port 80

```
ProxyPass /upload-test http://127.0.0.1/upload-test/
ProxyPassReverse /upload-test http://127.0.0.1/upload-test/
```

This is my upload method from angularjs

```
var fd = new FormData();
//Take the first selected file
fd.append($file, $files[0]);
console.log(fd);
$http.post('/upload-test',fd, {
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
    transformRequest: angular.identity
}).success(function(data,response){
    console.log("Inside Success Function ", response, data);
}).error(function(data,response){
    console.log("Inside Failure Function ", response, data);
});
```

Really appreciate your help

Comment: In your proxy pass configuration you have to set the target server port (9090) or it will use the default port 80

Comment: @Michael I am configuring it in the "000-default.conf" file which is located in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/". Is that correct way of configuring.  BTW,  I am Using Ubuntu OS

Answer (score 0):

I think thats the right location. As far as I remember all site-enabled are symbolic links to site-available.

I think your config should look like this:

```
ProxyPass /upload-test http://127.0.0.1:9090/upload-test/
ProxyPassReverse /upload-test http://127.0.0.1:9090/upload-test/
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but No luck . I would like to access the upload.php which is usually works, when I access "http://localhost/upload-test/" like this. I want to access the same from my AngularJS application using the url "http://localhost:9090/upload-test".

Comment: But then you don't need a proxy pass configuration for the upload-test. It's  already running on the 'proxy'. But maybe you configure a proxy pass for your angular server. So both apps are available on port 80, otherwise you need to support CORS.

Comment: Your `$http.post('/upload-test',fd, {` request doesn't provide another port. It will look for the upload-test on the same port as your angular app is running